# Unittest Django Model Permissions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

### How can I test for model custom permissions in my models?

---

I can normally do `user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')` for test if a user has `add_bar` permission in `bar`.

but this one don't seems to work `foo.has_perm('add_bar')` for check if `foo` has `add_bar` permission.

> AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'has_perm'

What I'm trying to do is

```
self.assertTrue(foo.has_perm('add_bar'))
```

My foo model looks like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                      editable=False,
                                      db_index=True)    
    class Meta:    
        permissions = (
            ('add_bar', 'Can add Bar'),
        )
```

Comment: What is `foo`, if it's a model then it won't have permissions since only users have permissions. Otherwise you need to add `permissions` to your models Meta options.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using an helper function and attributing it to the model `Foo.has_perm = model_has_perm_helper`

```
#imports omitted 

class FooTest(TestCase):
    """
    Test model and users permissions. Model level and object level
    """

    def setUp(self):
        # Do setup stuff here
        pass

    def test_permissions(self):
        Foo.has_perm = model_has_perm_helper
        self.assertTrue(union.has_perm('add_wedding'))
        # do others stuffs here, like check if user has that permission and such

def model_has_perm_helper(model, perm):
    """
    Helper function adds ability to call has_perm in model class
    """
    try:
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
        Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type, codename=perm)
    except:  #DoesNotExist error
        return False
    return True
```